# POST data to URL using PHP

Tags: php, post

I want to post an array or set of variable in a URL and post that data to that URL.

```
 i have a URL to post data  
 i have code igniter  
 i have to send data to that URL using code igniter function
```

So how should i send that data to that URL?
people say use curl PHP, i am a web developer using Linux but new to it, so kindly be easy.

Best Regards

Comment: You cannot *POST* data to *URL*

Comment: what kind of data you want to send? is it a form or what?

Comment: Yes you can, use Curl or something similar. That being said, this question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cURL is an easy way to send/retrieve data from other URLs. Personally, I find it to be fairly easy to use too -- you can see a tutorial [here](http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl). If you don't have cURL, there are [other options](http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/).

If you need to forward the user to another URL using POST, then you're in a bit more of a bind. HTTP was not designed that way. You can create a page on your side which has a form filled out with all of the post variables and have a script tag with `document.forms[0].submit()`.

Comment: i meant i want to send some information using post to an API in a url form

Comment: If you want the user to post to an outside URL, your best option is to have them post that data directly to the outside URL.